# Is there a standard way to make a dropdown navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, standards

What's the industry standard for building an interactive drop-down navigation menu?

Google tells me it *can* be done in all sorts of ways. As a student working on my first major web project, I'm wondering if there's a method that's standard practice. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, but I'm also not confident picking and trusting one of the hundreds of guides out there, knowing that it could be outdated or bad practice.

If there *is in fact* no standard way of doing it and no best-practice guidelines, let me know and I'll delete the question.

Comment: `<select>`? :p Just saying, it's by far the most browser-compatible way, and devices such as phones even have user-friendly native interfaces to handle them! (Except for some reason the DS browser doesn't actually let you `<select multiple>` - unless they fixed it since I reported it)

Comment: Just do `ul` > `li` > `ul`

Comment: I suppose I didn't make it explicitly that I meant a navigation-type menu, not a drop-down select, but I thought it was pretty damn obvious. Edited for clarity anyhow.

Comment: Edited the question again. If it still doesn't fit the rules, comment and I'll delete it. If not, I'd appreciate it being taken off hold.

Answer (score 1):

The most standard way is using a `select`.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Should be compatible with all browsers.
More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

If you want to get more funky, then you make use of CSS or JS.

Comment: my humble request is to avoid links to w3schools. it contains lots of outdated and misleading info. give reference to something like mdn

Comment: @TJ thanks, looks indeed better

Answer (score 0):

This code should be selfexplaining:

```
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

for any more questions see [MDN - select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)